# KendoUI MVVM Table of Contents style menu

Tags: templates, data-binding, mvvm, menu, kendo-ui

Been trying to use KendoUI templates and MVVM to create a menu that resembles a table of contents like so:

```
Lesson 1:
    - Slide 1
    - Slide 2
Lesson 2:
    - Slide 1
```

and so on. I have the following data that I've created a kendo.observable with:

```
var CourseData = kendo.observable({
    name: 'HTML Test Course',
    lessons: [
        { // Lesson 1
            name: 'Lesson 1',
            slides: [
                { // Slide 1.1
                    name: 'Animation',
                    type: 'CreateJS',
                    cctext: '<p>...</p>',
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```

Before discovering KendoUI I built the menu using plain JavaScript and for the given data it turns out like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span>Lesson 1</span>
        <ul>
            <li onclick="Shell.GoToSlide(1, 1)" class="unlocked"><!-- 0 = locked, 1 = unlocked, 2 = viewed, 3 = completed -->
                <span>Animation</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The two pieces of this puzzle that I am having trouble expressing together are the progress (noted by the class) and the click event. Progress is stored in either a jagged array right in CourseData (like `CourseData.progress = [[3]],` so `CourseData.progress[lesson][slide]` will give the progress of that slide.) or if it would better solve this conundrum I would consider moving it to each slide object (like `CourseData.lessons[lesson].slides[slide].progress`). The click event calls a navigation function written elsewhere that brings up the slides using their lesson and slide number (base 1) and is not added to the item if progress is locked.

With templates, I can do something like the following:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="coursemap-template">
    # for (var l = 0; l < lessons.length; l++) { #
    <li>
        <span>#: lessons[l].name #</span>
        <ul>
            # for (var s = 0; s < lessons[l].slides.length; s++) { #
            <li  onclick="Shell.GoToSlide(#: s + 1 #, #: l + 1 #)"><span>#: lessons[l].slides[s].name #</span></li>
            # } #
        </ul>
    </li>
    # } #
</script>
```

To get easy access to the indices of each lesson and slide, but it won't let me bind to a specific element in an array like: `data-bind="attr: { class: progress[l][s] }"` when Kendo evaluates this binding later it does not know what l and s are, nor can I think of an elegant way to translate the numbers into the appropriate strings. If I use `class="#: ['locked','unlocked','viewed','completed'][progress[l][s]] #"` it works but does not automatically update when the progress changed. If I used nested templates and made progress a property of slide I could bind to it no problem but then I wouldn't know how to get the lesson and slide indices for the click event without tons of indexOf calls or parent().parent() shenanigans. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the ideal solution, but this question has enough views that I suppose I should provide the code I used as a workaround:

**View:**

```
<ul id="coursemap"></ul>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
(function () {
    for (var l = 0; l < CourseData.lessons.length; l++) {
        var lessonItem = document.createElement('li');
        $(lessonItem).attr('data-bind', 'html: lessons[' + l + '].name');
        $('#coursemap').append(lessonItem);

        var slides = document.createElement('ul');
        for (var s = 0; s < CourseData.lessons[l].slides.length; s++) {
            var slideItem = document.createElement('li');
            $(slideItem).attr('data-bind', 'html: lessons[' + l + '].slides[' + s + '].name, attr: { data-progress: progress[' + l + '][' + s + '] }');

            (function (lesson, slide) {
                $(slideItem).click(function () {
                    // If the target slide is not locked, navigate.
                    if ($(this).attr('data-progress') != 0) {
                        Shell.GoToSlide(slide, lesson);
                        ExtensionManager.AutoHide();
                    }
                })
            })(l + 1, s + 1);

            $(slides).append(slideItem);
        }
        $('#coursemap').append(slides);
    }

    kendo.bind($('#coursemap'), CourseData);
})();
```